# Is It Possible to Tell the Python Interpreter to Sleep After Each Executed Statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an application that runs Python (3.5) code received over a network in an instance of `InteractiveConsole` and returns the output back to the user over the network (using asynchronous multicast UDP, not TCP). This is a hobby project, so taking every precaution one might want to in a professional application isn't necessary, but I am concerned about the application breaking under circumstances such as a `while` loop executing too quickly for the network to keep up with.

If it is possible, I could see addressing this by having the interactive console execute `time.sleep(0.25)` or something similar after any given statement is executed. The interactive console is running in its own thread, so stalling the rest of the application is not a concern.

I think this question is general enough that my code isn't necessary, but to save us all the trouble when I inevitably realize that it is, here is a slightly simplified snippet:

```
def recv_command(self, commands):
    # commands is a string containing a block of Python code
    console.runsource('exec("""'+commands+'""")')
    # output is sent over the network through a custom write() method
    # in the interactive console's stdout rather than explicitly on
    # each call of this method
```

If this is possible/practical, how would one go about doing so?

Comment: TCP already has flow control and congestion control built in. Per-statement sleeping isn't a good idea; for one thing, different statements generate vastly different amounts of network traffic.

Comment: I think your concern is likely unfounded.   there will typically be blocking on read/write methods to the remote that will pace things and avoid you getting out of synch.  only if you have gone seriously asynch in your handling and throwing off threads will you need to have the worries I think your having.

Comment: @user2357112 All messages to be transmitted are added to a queue, which is continuously flushed in its own thread. I could see that queue getting backed up enough that what the client is seeing (in addition to console output, there is a data structure that users collectively interact with) is out of sync with the host state. Also, I am using UDP for multicast

Comment: @Rammschnev: If you want to ensure that the client's view is synchronized with the state of the server, why not actually synchronize the message-sending thread and the command-executing thread, or even perform those tasks in one thread? You seem to be creating unnecessary problems for yourself.

Comment: @user2357112 There are other types of messages, such as chat messages and new user connections (which I am handling myself, since I'm using UDP), that need to be handled as well, so I can't allow the serving thread to get hung on an infinite loop caused by the console or the whole thing will shut down

Comment: @lhasadad I am using UDP multicast, which as far as I'm aware doesn't manage whether or not the data was received successfully. It is very deliberately asynchronous because there are several different systems that utilize the socket

Comment: When the output queue is too full (for whatever definition of full you prefer) lock it until the flushing thread gets its size back under some mark; in the meanwhile, threads trying to add messages will hang on the queue lock.

Comment: @MatteoItalia That is an excellent idea. I'm currently using a simple list for my queues, but I can create a custom class with a `write` method that stays caught in a `while` loop until the lock is released so that any thread that interacts with the queue will become locked. Thanks much

Comment: @Rammschnev  I hope you are not doing a hot spin? there are better mechanisms than that...

Comment: @Ihasadad I'm not familiar with the term, and a search didn't pull anything up, but if you mean continuously running input and output queues in their own threads, yes, that's what I'm doing. This is my first application with networking, so I would not be surprised at all to learn that there's a better method. It seemed like the best thing for the number of different components that need to interact asynchronously.

Comment: @rammschnev what I meant by a hot spin was a spin loop where you are looping checking an item without doing something to yield  the CPU or block until some event occurs

Comment: @Ihasadad I don't quite understand what you mean. In what context do you mean 'checking an item?' As in when a new message comes in through the socket? There is nothing I'm doing that requires yielding the CPU. There are four threads: two for in and out queues, one for processing messages in the in queue, and one main thread for setting up the app/GUI. That's probably a fairly simplistic design, but is it what you're describing?